# Require dynamic class using namespace in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, require

I was studying a couple PHP frameworks and then decided to build my own, of course. But i'm facing one issue. I have a Router class that handles  dynamically the HTTP requests and it basically explodes the URL into elements dividing it by the slash and storing it into an array, then a function is called to check if the first element is a valid Controller. If it is valid, the function should require it, but that's where i'm stuck, because it seems that i can't require a file like:

```
if (file_exists(CONTROLLERS_DIR . $this->url[0] . '.php')) { require \App\Controllers\$this->url[0] }
```

How can I require a file like that using namespaces?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (file_exists(CONTOLLERS_DIR . $this->url[0])) { require CONTOLLERS_DIR . $this->url[0] }` ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you checked the value of `$this->url[0]`? Is it correct?

Comment: Actually, i'm using an autoloader, so i don't need to check if the file exists. I just need to require it. I just used it here to simply explain what i'm going though...by the way, the error i got is: 'unexpected $this after / should be identifier'.

Comment: But i still cant do this: new \App\Controllers\$this->url[0];

Comment: You cannot perform a string concat in a require/include statement. `$ctrl = '\\App\\Contrllers\\'.$this->url[0]; $c = new $ctrl;` oh you gotta escape your slashes too. see here for how i accomplished this: https://github.com/r3wt/RedBeanFVM/blob/master/RedBeanFVM/RedBeanFVM.php#L58

Comment: Nice!! It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

*"How can I require a file like that using namespaces?"*
You can't. Namespaces have nothing to do with it.

> "PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants." ~ [Namespaces overview](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

---

[`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) is about file dependancies, regardless the namespace:

```
if (file_exists(CONTROLLERS_DIR . $this->url[0] . '.php')) { 
    require(CONTROLLERS_DIR . $this->url[0] . '.php');
}
```

---

**EDIT**: You might want to instantiate a class using a namespace and class name retrieved in run-time though, i.e. something like:

```
namespace \App\Controllers;
class C {
    protected $_i;
    public function __construct($i){ $this->_i = $i; }
    public function foo(){ echo $this->_i; }
}
```

and somewhere:

```
$className = "C";                   // or $className = $this->whatever...
$class = "\\App\\Controllers\\".$className;
$instance = new $class(7);
$instance->foo();                   // outputs 7
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Edit: maybe it does but its still not concise enough of an  answer. please revise.

Comment: @r3wt: I agree, have a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

I've built couple of frameworks and I understand what you trying to do...
Basically when you have some path for example "HelloWorld\addComment"

You want to **create** controller instance

```
\App\Controllers\HelloWorldController
```

There are multiple ways to solve it, the one I like is:

Using spl autoloader
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

In the link I provided you got the examples you need.

Then you can end up just doing

```
$controller = new \App\Controllers\HelloWorldController();
```

You should put the HelloWorldController at the right namespace + maintain directory structure matching the namespace

```
app     
   Controllers
       HelloWorldController
```

spl autoloader will do the right including for you, often the default implementation is sufficient - but it is easy to create your own spl autoloader and [register it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Later you can test if the $controller has the method you need via method_exist or reflection...